# SETUP OF CONTRACTS usig .NET 3.5 and VS2008 (FOR FACEBOOK C# SDK)

Tags: .net, facebook-c#-sdk

I would need to use Facebook C# SDK with .NET 3.5 and VS2008 (without installing .NET 4.0).
I have downloaded the Code Contracts set up file from the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx, but when I try to install them I receive a message about the .net 4.0 requirement. How can I set up them and use them in .net 3.5 and VS2008? I have read that I would need only to link the Microsoft.Contracts.dll on my project. But how can I get that assembly?

Answer (score 0):

download the source code of Facebook C# SDK and you can find the code contracts library for .net 3.5 in the following folder

```
Source\packages\CodeContracts.Unofficial.1.0.0.2\lib\net35-client\Microsoft.Contracts.dll
```